# Novel with teens with mental powers escaping from a facility

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am certain it may have been a sequel or series.
I read this book when I was a a young girl between 2007-2010 maybe? I could be way off!!

I don’t remember the author or any of the characters names but I vaguely remember the storyline and a few events that transpired.

So this book is about a young girl who’s in some sort of facility - i remember descriptions of white walls and long hallways. She however found this garden with a pond or some kind of water feature that she liked to hide away in. At this facility she found a group of other teens, one of those a mysterious boy whom surprise surprise she falls in love with.

I remember two events from the book. They escape from this facility and somehow wind up at some kind of store or warehouse and steal some clothes and cut/dye their hair as the people from the facility are now hunting for them.

I feel like this girl and the other teens had some sort of powers like she could teleport or had telekinesis or something. I remember them being at a cafe and needing some money to survive so they come up with a plan for the girl to (I think) teleport behind the counter when the waitress goes out back and steal some money.

That’s it. That’s all I remember!

Comment: Did it include a plotline involving a prop dragon in the warehouse that they wind up using?

Comment: Tomorrow People?

Answer (score -2):

Is it [The Summoning](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2800905) by Kelley Armstrong?

> But now she finds herself in the middle of some really strange situations because:
> ~She suddenly starts seeing dead people.
> ~She gets locked up in a group home for unstable teens.
> ~The group home isn't what it seems.
>
> My name is Chloe Saunders and my life will never be the same again.
>
> All I wanted was to make friends, meet boys, and keep on being ordinary. I don't even know what that means anymore. It all started on the day that I saw my first ghost—and the ghost saw me.
>
> Now there are ghosts everywhere and they won't leave me alone. To top it all off, I somehow got myself locked up in Lyle House, a "special home" for troubled teens. Yet the home isn't what it seems. Don't tell anyone, but I think there might be more to my housemates than meets the eye. The question is, whose side are they on? It's up to me to figure out the dangerous secrets behind Lyle House... before its skeletons come back to haunt me.
>
> [image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you describe this story a bit, and explain how it matches the question?